# Django Rest Framework Serializer из двух моделей

Tags: django, python-3.x, rest, django-rest-framework

Здравствуйте. Есть 2 модели Django

```
class Aaaa(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    LastUpdate = models.DateTimeField('date update')

class Bbbb (models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    LastAuth = models.DateTimeField()
```

Не совсем могу понять как в DRF сделать так, чтобы при запросе GET сначала считывалась информация из класса Bbbb (в частности поле LastAuth), а потом по нему уже шла фильтрация (Aaa.LastUpdate > Bbbb. LastAuth) в поле LastUpdate из Класса AAAA и на выходе выдавались только поля **Aaaaa**

Comment: Скореее всего нужно переопределить `queryset` и просто создать обычный `Serializer` для `Aaaa`.

Comment: Можеш показать как связаны у тебя эти модели, как ты знаешь какую запись сравнивать с какой в другой таблице? Напиши весь код модели, и я напишу тебе ответ точнее.

Comment: Извините, когого вы спрашиваете? ТС последний раз заходил в мае 2017. Он вряд ли ответит. Дайте ответ без уточнений по содержанию вопроса.